# Seleccionar elemento lista que no este en la tabla

Tags: java, selenium

Necesitaria seleccionar un elemento de la lista desplegable de abajo que no este ya en la tabla de arriba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso no podría seleccionar el primer elemento , por ejemplo.

Esto es lo que tengo de código: en ambas lista se obtiene tanto el contenido de la tabla como el del desplegable.

```
    tabla = new TableOne(driver,"",XPATH_TABLE_CLIENTES,XPATH_TABLE_ROW_CLIENTES);
    List<WebElement> columnas = tabla.getColumn(1);
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='slct_listaFondos']")));
    List<WebElement> opciones = select.getOptions();

    for(WebElement a : columnas){
        for(WebElement b : opciones){
           if(a.getText().contains(b.getText())) {
               //
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Deberías poner lo que has intentado de código

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un filtro

```
opciones.stream().filter ...
```

Para obtener una lista de los valores que no están en columnas